# Opening a file with O_WRONLY flag but without write permissions

Tags: permissions, filesystems, cifs

I've noticed that it's possible to `open(...)` a file with `O_CREAT|O_WRONLY` flags, but with `0400` mode (that is without `w`), then write data to the file and close it.

This is somewhat contradictory to me, but I can understand how it could work.

However, I've recently run into problems with this approach in a CIFS mounted filesystem.

Now I'm curious which of the following two statements is true:

- This is technically (POSIX) an "unsupported/undocumented" feature that just so happens to work on some filesystems.

*or*

- The fact that it does not work on CIFS a shortcoming of how CIFS is implemented.

I've search for an authoritative answer but can't find it. References to some official POSIX standard would be great.

Comment: On what unix, filesystem, and as what user were your tests run as?

Comment: CentOS 7 in this case. CIFS mounted with `vers=2.1`. Tests run as a regular user (not super user).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've noticed that it's possible to open(...) a file with O_CREAT|O_WRONLY flags, but with 0400 mode (that is without w), then write data to the file and close it.

This is consistent with how changing the permission bits does *not* affect the access of already opened file descriptors.  Conceptually, you could imagine creating the file with permissions `0600`, then opening it in write-only mode, and then changing the permissions to `0400`. Just that the system does all that atomically, without letting other processes also open it for writing in the middle.

I can't see [the description of the `open()` system call](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) explicitly say that you can do that, but I think it's implied in how `O_WRONLY` controls the permissions the opened fd gets, and the distinct *mode* argument controls the permission bits set to the created file. Two different things, and it **doesn't** say they need to be related in any way.

Also, the description of EACCES says:

> [EACCES]
> Search permission is denied on a component of the path prefix, **or the file exists and the permissions specified by *oflag* are denied**, or the file does not exist and write permission is denied for the parent directory of the file to be created, or O_TRUNC is specified and write permission is denied.

i.e. the permission bits only apply for a file that already exist. But I'm not sure how far one can sanely assume the listed standard error conditions could be the only possible error conditions.

Insofar as CIFS comes from a somewhat different tradition, I wouldn't expect this to be the only way it differs from "traditional" Unixy filesystems, or the POSIX specifications.